GAS　トリガー設定画面　鉛筆マークが無い
GoogleAppsScriptのトリガー設定画面で
昨日気づいたのですが、
一度トリガーを設定すると、
そのトリガーの行の右端に、
鉛筆マークと縦の点３つが表示されますが
鉛筆マークが表示されないものがある事に気づきました
今までそのような事は無かったのですが・・・
トリガーの実行時間を変える際は、
そのトリガーを削除し新しいトリガーを設定する必要が出てきます
これは最近できた仕様なのでしょうか？
今のところ　大きな支障とはなっていませんが・・
